# shared_ptr and weak_ptr differences

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, weak-ptr, cyclic-reference

I am reading Scott Meyers "Effective C++" book. It was mentioned that there are `tr1::shared_ptr` and `tr1::weak_ptr` act like built-in pointers, but they keep track of how many `tr1::shared_ptrs` point to an object.

This is known as reference counting. This works well in preventing resource leaks in acyclic data structures, but if two or more objects contain `tr1::shared_ptrs` such that a cycle is formed, the cycle may keep each other's reference count above zero, even when all external pointers to the cycle have been destroyed.

That's where `tr1::weak_ptrs` come in.

My question is how cyclic data structures make the reference count above zero. I kindly request an example C++ program. How is the problem solved by `weak_ptrs`? (again, with example please).

Comment: "_How is the problem solved by weak_ptrs?_" It is not. It is solved by proper design, where no ownership cycle exists.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

A `shared_ptr` wraps a reference counting mechanism around a raw pointer. So for each instance of the `shared_ptr` the reference count is increased by one. If two `share_ptr` objects refer the each other they will never get deleted because they will never end up with a reference count of zero.

`weak_ptr` points to a `shared_ptr` but does not increase its reference count.This means that the underying object can still be deleted even though there is a `weak_ptr` reference to it.

The way that this works is that the `weak_ptr` can be use to create a `shared_ptr` for whenever one wants to use the underlying object. If however the object has already been deleted then an empty instance of a `shared_ptr` is returned. Since the reference count on the underlying object is not increased with a `weak_ptr` reference, a circular reference will not result in the underlying object not being deleted.

Comment: I believe that the reference control object keeps a count of both "Uses"(shared_ptrs) and "Weaks" (weak_ptrs + (Uses > 0 ? 1 : 0 )). But this might be an implimentation detail.

Answer (score 135):

Let me repeat your question: "My question, how cyclic data structures makes reference count above zero, kindly request to show with example in C++ program. How the problem is solved by `weak_ptrs` again with example please."

The problem occurs with C++ code like this (conceptually):

```
class A { shared_ptr<B> b; ... };
class B { shared_ptr<A> a; ... };
shared_ptr<A> x(new A);  // +1
x->b = new B;            // +1
x->b->a = x;             // +1
// Ref count of 'x' is 2.
// Ref count of 'x->b' is 1.
// When 'x' leaves the scope, there will be a memory leak:
// 2 is decremented to 1, and so both ref counts will be 1.
// (Memory is deallocated only when ref count drops to 0)
```

To answer the second part of your question: It is mathematically impossible for reference counting to deal with cycles. Therefore, a `weak_ptr` (which is basically just a stripped down version of `shared_ptr`) **cannot** be used to solve the cycle problem - the programmer is solving the cycle problem.

To solve it, the programmer needs to be aware of the **ownership** relationship among the objects, or needs to invent an ownership relationship if no such ownership exists naturally.

The above C++ code can be changed so that A owns B:

```
class A { shared_ptr<B> b; ... };
class B { weak_ptr<A>   a; ... };
shared_ptr<A> x(new A); // +1
x->b = new B;           // +1
x->b->a = x;            // No +1 here
// Ref count of 'x' is 1.
// Ref count of 'x->b' is 1.
// When 'x' leaves the scope, its ref count will drop to 0.
// While destroying it, ref count of 'x->b' will drop to 0.
// So both A and B will be deallocated.
```

A crucial question is: Can `weak_ptr` be used in case the programmer cannot tell the ownership relationship and cannot establish any static ownership because of lack of privilege or lack of information?

The answer is: If ownership among objects is unclear, `weak_ptr` **cannot** help. If there is a cycle, the programmer has to find it and break it. An alternative remedy is to use a programming language with full garbage collection (such as: Java, C#, Go, Haskell), or to use a conservative (=imperfect) garbage collector which works with C/C++ (such as: Boehm GC).

Comment: But all uses of `B::a` must now be prepared the weak reference to be dead. If this must not be the case, then it means `weak_ptr` is not an adequat tool.

Comment: If B::a is a weak_ptr, then nothing should depend on it's existence - as it does not own a. A::b is the dependable guy here.

Comment: I would have chosen yours as best answer. But hey.. not my choice :) +1 btw

Answer (score 21):

For future readers.
Just want to point out that explanation given by Atom is excellent, here is working code

```
#include <memory> // and others
using namespace std;

    class B; // forward declaration 
    // for clarity, add explicit destructor to see that they are not called
    class A { public: shared_ptr<B> b; ~A() {cout << "~A()" << endl; } };  
    class B { public: shared_ptr<A> a; ~B() {cout << "~B()" << endl; } };     
    shared_ptr<A> x(new A);  //x->b share_ptr is default initialized
    x->b = make_shared<B>(); // you can't do "= new B" on shared_ptr                      
    x->b->a = x;
    cout << x.use_count() << endl;
```

Comment: Is weak_ptr just for cyclic reference or Cache?

Answer (score 9):

Weak pointers just "observe" the managed object; they don't "keep it alive" or affect its lifetime. Unlike `shared_ptr`, when the last `weak_ptr` goes out of scope or disappears, the pointed-to object can still exist because the `weak_ptr` does not affect the lifetime of the object - it has no ownership rights. The `weak_ptr` can be used to determine whether the object exists, and to provide a `shared_ptr` that can be used to refer to it.

The definition of `weak_ptr` is designed to make it relatively foolproof, so as a result there is very little you can do directly with a `weak_ptr`. For example, you can't dereference it; neither `operator*` nor `operator->` is defined
for a `weak_ptr`. You can't access the pointer to the object with it - there is no `get()` function. There is a comparison function defined so that you can store `weak_ptrs` in an ordered container, but that's all.

Answer (score -9):

All the above answer are WRONG. `weak_ptr` is NOT used to break cyclic references, they have another purpose.

Basically, if all `shared_ptr(s)` were created by `make_shared()` or `allocate_shared()` calls, you will NEVER need `weak_ptr` if you have no resource other than memory to manage. These functions create the `shared_ptr` reference counter object with the object itself, and the memory will be freed at the same time.

The only difference between `weak_ptr` and `shared_ptr` is that the `weak_ptr` allows the reference counter object to be kept after the actual object was freed. As a result, if you keep a lot of `shared_ptr` in a `std::set` the actual objects will occupy a lot of memory if they are big enough. This problem can be solved by using `weak_ptr` instead. In this case, you have to ensure the `weak_ptr` stored in the container is not expired before using it.

Comment: "_weak_ptr is NOT used to break cyclic references_" +1 "_they have other purpose._" but that answer doesn't explain the release purpose, so -1

Comment: "_if all shared_ptr(s) were created by make_shared()_" then you don't need `shared_ptr` (`unique_ptr` is more appropriate). The value of reference counting is when multiple objects hold references. This happens through assignments, like the very fine example.