# Is it possible to create weak pointer for c style pointer or raw pointer in c++17

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a third party library which has a lot of c-style raw pointer. Now i am writing a thread in c++ 17. i want to use weak pointer for c style pointers of library. this library can be used by many other thread which modify/delete same pointers. how it can be achieved? is there any design pattern which can help?

In library :

```
struct table *table = (struct table *) malloc(sizeof(table));
```

Now in my thread:

```
auto wp = std::make_weak<struct table* >(table)
```

Comment: Why a weak pointer? Why not a shared pointer? And inside your application, perhaps you should write a wrapper-class for the library (with all access to the library should go through the wrapper-class, and not directly)?

Comment: A weak ptr cant hold a raw pointer. That's the whole idea behind a weak ptr. It only points to a different type smart pointer that manages ownership and deletion.

Comment: Perhaps you should first start out with determining who owns the pointers versus who is referring to the pointed to objects but doesn't actually own the pointers and the objects being pointed to.  See [When is std::weak_ptr useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030650/when-is-stdweak-ptr-useful) as well as [shared_ptr and weak_ptr differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984381/shared-ptr-and-weak-ptr-differences) as the answers to these have some interesting discussions about pointer ownership.

Comment: Consider using `std::unique_ptr`. Only use `std::shared_ptr + std::weak_ptr` when nothing else does.

Answer (score 0):

One of the *fatal* problems with owing raw pointers, is that there is *nothing* you can do to observe that *somewhere else* has invalidated your pointer. Smart pointers work by tracking who knows about the object, and only destroying when the last pointer is destroyed.

`std::weak_ptr` is a complement to `std::shared_ptr` and nothing else. It does not magically know when `delete` is called on the object it is pointing to, it uses the same mechanism that `std::shared_ptr` does to know about the object's lifetime. Notice there is no constructor of `std::weak_ptr` that accepts a raw pointer.

If the library is managing the ownership, it is *incorrect* for you to put them into a smart pointer that uses `std::default_delete`. The best you can do is use the library's `release` function as the deleter of your smart pointers, and wrap the `create` function so that you return such a smart pointer instead of the raw one.

Comment: Terminology: "when the last pointer" last owner? last `shared_ptr`? last strong ref?

Comment: @curiousguy for both `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`, the last owning pointer

Comment: OK ... although neither `std::shared_ptr` nor `std::unique_ptr`, they are classes. Only pointers (scalars) are really pointers.

Comment: @curiousguy if you are going to be pedantic, they are *templates*. But they are templates for classes with pointer semantics, which is sufficient for a colloquial discussion, especially when using the qualifer "raw pointers" for things shaped `T*`

Comment: Not trying to be "pedantic", but these so called "smart pointers" don't even have a conversion to a real pointer. (Also, almost all use practical uses of a `std::shared_ptr` are going to be on specializations of the template, that's why I mentioned classes not templates.)